# Rails: RSpec controller test passes without action being implemented, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following RSpec example which is passing:

```
describe UsersController  do
  it "should render new template on new action" do
    get :new
    response.should render_template("users/new")
  end
end
```

The problem is I have not implemented the 'new' action on the UsersController.
Can anyone tell me why this test is passing?
I am new to RSpec, so any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When requesting an action for which a **view exists**, but the **action is not defined**, Rails will simply render the view. Therefore your spec (correctly) passes.

In addition to this spec, you may want to test for the assignment of particular instance variables. Example:

```
it "should assign the found articles for the view" do
  assigns[:article].should == [@article]
end
```

Comment: Why then when I browse to "/users/new" do I receive "Unknown action
No action responded to new." ?